# Issue with Unity IAP on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

Good morning!

I've been stuck on this issue for months now, hopefully someone can help me.

This code on iOS works fine, but not on Android.

There are three items to be purchased: 
- productMonthlySub
- productUnlockAll
- productUnlockLevel[]

The only one that works, for some reason, is the last one. The others are initialised correctly, but act like if they didn't exist.

Keystore is correct, same with the dev console stuff, or all three would fail. Checked for typos many, many times.

Pasting the full code as I'm desperate: http://pastebin.com/x8pNT10S

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You are definitely sure that 1) the products are initialized, 2) you can purchase the 3rd product, and I assume 3) all 3 products are active in dev console, and also 4) your app is not in draft? If all this is true, then I think something isn't properly set up in your dev console, curious part is that subscription is working, the however the nonconsumables don't, I assume your non-consum products are set to managed?

Comment: All the assumptions you named are correct. Issue lies elsewhere...